# Java ProgressBar gui builder netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, progress-bar

I want to use `ProgressBar` from netbeans GUI builder.
Any example will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun/ Orcale's Java Tutorial is always good start to look for such information:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple ProgressBar Demo Program

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class ProgressBarDemo {

    JFrame frame;
    JProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressBarDemo() {
        frame = new JFrame("ProgressBarDemo");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressBarDemo();
    }

}
```

Comment: but how to use GUI Builder progress bar in Netbeans.